# Android (Java) - lookup contact by email and preview if exists

Tags: java, android

Right now we have an app where we (after permissions) lookup a contact, and if they exist, display their contact card.  However the lookup seems very inefficient, it loops through everyone, doesn't seem right.  Is there a better query contacts db to lookup ONLY contacts that have an email address that we need?

Current Code Below (not efficient):

```
public static void showCardIfPossible(String email, Context context) {
        Long contactId = lookupByEmail(email, context);
        if (contactId != null) {
            viewCardFor(context, contactId);
        }
    }

    public static Long lookupByEmail(String email, Context context) {

        Long contactId = null;

        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            Cursor cur1 = cr.query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                    new String[]{id}, null);

            if (cur1 != null && cur1.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cur1.moveToNext()) {
                    //to get the contact names
                    String contactName=cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String contactEmail = cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                    if(email.equals(contactEmail) || email.equals(contactName)){
                        contactId = Long.valueOf(id);
                    }
                }
                cur1.close();
            }
        }
        cursor.close();

        return contactId;
    }

    public static void viewCardFor(Context context, long contactId) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(contactId));
        intent.setData(uri);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can just query directly on the `Email.CONTENT_URI` and using selection to find the right contact:

```
public static Long lookupByEmail(String email, Context context) {

    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Long contactId = null;

    String[] projection = new String[] { Email.CONTACT_ID };
    String selection = Email.ADDRESS + "='" + email + "'";
    Cursor cur = cr.query(Email.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

    if (cur != null) {
       if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
          contactId = cur.getLong(0);      
       }
       cur.close();
    }

    return contactId;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This worked.  Only had to make a slight change to include single quotes around email, otherwise SDK would make faulty search query.  String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS + "='" + email + "'";

Comment: yes, right, I've forgot about that... answer updated.